# A few sites are showing up as having no questions or answers on the network-wide stats

Tags: bug, status-norepro, stack-exchange, network-statistics

At the bottom of [this list](https://stackexchange.com/sites#users), I see:

[image: screenshot]

I don't think this even needs hand-drawn circles to highlight the problem.

Something to do with the recent HTTP -> HTTPS change, maybe?

Comment: Obviously a bug, I don't know how a site can have 106 questions per day if it hasn't got any questions

Comment: @Beastly Unless "0" is Spanish for "lots".

Comment: I can reproduce on Safari on iOS 10.3.1.  I doubt it's an HTTPS thing, since only 4 sites are affected.

Comment: Give em a break, they've only existed for 7 minutes! :P (repro'd on Chrome/Ubuntu ???.???.??)

Comment: Still? No repro here (...oh my bad, sorted by answers and Stack Overflow en español is still borked, but only that)

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce on Chrome or IE.

Comment: No repro here on Chrome on a really crappy VPN.

Comment: No repro here. Is this still happening?

Comment: @AdamLear No, I'm not seeing the problem any more. Want to slap a [meta-tag:status-norepro] on this, or shall I just delete it?

Comment: @randal'thor Why not both? ;) Seriously, though - either is fine. I retagged; leaving the "delete or not" call up to you.